# AADSTS90094: is requesting permissions, which you are not authorized to grant. Contact your administrator, who can grant permissions

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, office365

I'm using Xamarin forms and azure portal i was trying to authenticate user's with office 365 but this message appeared

Need admin approval

Request Id: ddda1a97-9ae9-xxxxxxxx-6c7638919f00
Correlation Id: 9571fe55-4e9d-xxxxxxxxx-b7371vfa860f
Timestamp: 2019-03-26T09:18:36Z
Message: AADSTS90094: AuthPegasus is requesting permissions, which you are not authorized to grant. Contact your administrator, who can grant permissions to this application on your behalf
I Do i need to add user's ?? How  ??

I added the application in azure active directory and enter the redirect url and configured my app

I can authenticate with the admin account but user's i receive this message please i have a lot of user's that need to authenticate

THANK YOU

Comment: You should make an authorization request to Azure AD that includes the parameter prompt=admin_consent.

Go to a URL such as https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/oauth2/authorize?client_id=app-client-id&redirect_uri=encoded-reply-url&response_type=code&prompt=admin_consent.

Use your admin account to consent the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

When you grant permissions in Azure AD, there are a number of these that require administrator approval.

Anything you add to the application with the "YES" in the "Requires Admin" column needs to be approved by an AD administrator.

[image]

For obvious reasons, checks and balances need to be put in place so that the developer cannot simply add permissions to an application without the consent of the higher security/admin teams.

A user will typically blindly ok any request for access, this is in place to ensure that at least 1 other person has given the ok for your app to ask for those permissions.